# Angular JS syntax error when using .$valid templating in ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I'm getting the following error

> Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [rForm{{index}}.$valid && rCtrl.saveResource(api)] starting at [{{index}}.$valid && rCtrl.saveResource(api].

My form code is as follows

```
<form name ="rForm{{index}}" ng-submit="rForm{{index}}.$valid && rCtrl.saveResource(api)" style="margin-top:0%" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
```

I'm using `{{index}}` from `ng-repeat` since I'm making multiple forms dynamically. The final html rendered is exactly as I want as below

```
<form name="rForm0" ng-submit="rForm0.$valid &amp;&amp; rCtrl.saveResource(api)" style="margin-top:0%" class="form-horizontal ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" role="form">
```

But angular is going crazy at my template `{{index}}.$valid` and not showing the expected behavior. Please help me solve this!

P.S my html code is being hidden by stackoverflow.

Comment: I think that you forgot $ prifix put before index

Comment: try: `ng-submit="rForm[index].$valid &&`, you don't need for interpolation